# Why does conceptual class template specialization cause an error

Tags: template-specialization, c++20, c++-concepts, class-template, gcc10

I tried to build the following with gcc 10 `-std=gnu++20 -fconcepts`:

```
template <std::signed_integral T>
class MyClass{ T a; };

template <std::unsigned_integral T>
class MyClass{ T a; };
```

Why does this code cause the following error?

```
> declaration of template parameter ‘class T’ with different constraints
> 55 | template <std::unsigned_integral T>
>       |           ^~~
```

Shouldn't it be fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be fine?

No, constraints don't make classes "overloadable". You still need a primary template and then you need to specialize that template:

```
template <std::integral T>
class MyClass;

template <std::signed_integral T>
class MyClass<T>{ T a; };

template <std::unsigned_integral T>
class MyClass<T>{ T a; };
```